# Safe, signed subtraction of large unsigned ints

Tags: c++, types, boost, binary

I'm working with a protocol where I don't have control of the input types. But I need to compute the difference in two, 64-bit unsigned integers (currently baked into a `std::uint64_t`). But the difference might be negative or positive. I don't want to do this:

```
uint64_t a{1};
uint64_t b{2};
int64_t x = a - b; // -1; correct, but what if a and b were /enormous/?
```

So I was looking at Boost's `safe_numerics` [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/index.html). The large-values case is handled as I would like:

```
boost::safe_numerics::safe<uint64_t> a{UINT64_MAX};
boost::safe_numerics::safe<uint64_t> b{1};
boost::safe_numerics::safe<int64_t> x = a - b;
// ^^ Throws "converted unsigned value too large: positive overflow error"
```

Great! But ... they're a little *too* safe:

```
boost::safe_numerics::safe<uint64_t> a{1}; //UINT64_MAX;
boost::safe_numerics::safe<uint64_t> b{2};
boost::safe_numerics::safe<int64_t> x = a - b;
// ^^ Throws "subtraction result cannot be negative: negative overflow error"
//    ... even though `x` is signed
```

I have a suspicion that it's `a - b` that actually throws, not the assignment. But I've tried every kind of cast in the book to get `a - b` into a safe, signed integer, but no joy.

There are some inelegant ways to deal with this, like comparing `a` and `b` to always subtract the smaller from the larger. Or I can do a lot of casting with `boost::numeric_cast`, or old-school range checking. Or...god forbid...I just throw myself when `a` or `b` exceed 63 bits, but all that is a bit lame.

But my real question is: Why does Boost detect a negative overflow in the final example above? Am I using `safe_numerics` incorrectly?

Am targeting C++-17 with gcc on a 64-bit system and using Boost 1.71.

Comment: `boost::safe_numerics::safe<int64_t> x = a>b ? a - b : b - a ; x = a>b ? x : -x;`

Comment: Yeah, that's (short-hand for) the kind of thing I might have to do, but still, where's the negative underflow coming from?

Comment: What are you supposed to return if `a == 0` and `b == std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`?

Comment: The `a - b` happens before the `=`.  That's where the negative underflow is coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure why your are confused.  `unsigned(1) - unsigned(2)` is unsigned integer underflow.

Comment: btw `boost::safe_numerics::safe<int64_t> x = a - b;` is not assignment.

Comment: So in the first example, `signed(x) = unsigned(1) - unsigned(2)` works as I'd expect. Is that a happy accident? But basically, want to throw if `a - b` can't fit into a signed 64-bit int, otherwise, I want the result.

Comment: try `std::cout << (a-b);` with your very first example. https://godbolt.org/z/P8nEaG6jj  It wraps around, and `boost::safe_numeric` reports that

Comment: Ahh ... yeah. Ugh. Ok, so ... new question: Is @Eljay's solution above the best I can do? Seems like there ought to be a magic type that solves (wraps) this behaviour.

Comment: You can make your own type to wrap this behavior.  That's pretty much what user-defined types are for.

Comment: Turns out, Boost does solve exactly this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/checked_arithmetic.html  `checked_result<int64_t> x = checked::subtract<int64_t>(a, b);`

Comment: Eljay or 463035818_is_not_a_number feel free to post an answer if you want; you were both really helpful.

Comment: With `std::uint64_t`, you can use the fact that subtraction wraps (modulo arithmetic).   So if `uint64_t x = a - b`  gives a result that exceeds `a` then overflow occurred, and the mathematical result (essentially - the difference you would calculate on paper) is negative.   You also need to specify and handle cases where the difference (whether signed or not) between `a` and `b` is outside the range of values that a `int64_t` can represent.  Consider, for example, if `a` is `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`,  and `b` is zero.

Comment: @gerowam we helped to point to your misunderstandings but it was you who found the answer. You can write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior I was looking for is actually implemented in `boost::safe_numerics::checked_result`:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/checked_result.html

`checked::subtract` allows negative overflows when the difference of two unsigned integers is negative (and being stored in a signed integer of adequate size). But it throws when the result does not. For example:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::safe_numerics;

safe<uint64_t> a{2};
safe<uint64_t> b{1};

checked_result<int64_t> x0 = checked::subtract<int64_t>(b, a);
assert(x0 == -1);

checked_result<int64_t> x1 = checked::subtract<int64_t>(a, b);
assert(x1 == 1);

a = UINT64_MAX;
checked_result<int64_t> x2 = checked::subtract<int64_t>(a, b); // throws
```